# Using Match() instead of Find() in Excel macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I've been using a macro for about 11 years without any problems. However, over the past 18 months some of the workbooks I've been using it on are very large and in these cases the macro can take a long time to run.

To address this I modified the macro to disable events and screen updating, and to make calculations 'manual'. This significantly improved things, but sometimes the improvements aren't enough.

For example, yesterday I ran the macro to compare a list of 288,000 email addresses against another list of 235,000 email addresses to identify any matches. This took about 14 hours to complete (and therefore beyond a typical work day).

I've done some research ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404152/excel-vba-iterate-through-columns-in-one-workbook-pasting-information-in-corre/19410285#19410285), [2](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/), etc) and have identified that using `Match()` will be much faster than `Find()`.

However, I am having problems modifying the code to use `Match()`. Below is the current working code that uses `Find()`:

```
Sub FindMatchingData()

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim MySearchRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim findC As Variant

Set MyRange = Application.InputBox( _
Prompt:="Select the range of cells containing the data you are looking for:", Type:=8)

Set MySearchRange = Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:="Select the range you wish to investigate:", Type:=8)

Response = InputBox(Prompt:="Specify the comment you wish to appear to indicate the data was found:")

MyOutputColumn = Application.InputBox( _
Prompt:="Enter the alphabetical column letter(s) to specify the column you want the message to appear in.")
    
Set Sht = MyRange.Parent

  For Each c In MyRange
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
    
Set findC = MySearchRange.Find(c.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not findC Is Nothing Then
           Sht.Range(MyOutputColumn & c.Row).Cells.Value = Response
        End If
    End If
  Next
Excel.Application.SendKeys Keys:="^{HOME}", Wait:=True
DoEvents

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Investigation completed."

End Sub
```

**QUESTION:**

- Can someone advise whether the above code can be amended easily to
  use Match() instead, or am I better off starting totally from
  scratch?
- If it can be amended, any help would be greatly appreciated
  as I seem to be hitting a brick wall.

---

**ADDITIONAL INFO: EXPECTED BEHAVIOUR OF THE MACRO**

This macro provides an easy way for users to find matching data between two ranges, either within the same worksheet or across worksheets within the same workbook.

The expected behaviour is as follows:

1. it prompts the user to:

- select the range containing the data they're looking for
- select the range to be searched to see if the data also exists there
- enter a comment that is used to indicate any matching data
- enter the column you want the comment populated into if a match was found

2. Excel then proceeds to run the comparison between the selected ranges and starts populating the selected column wherever matches are found.
3. When complete it presents the user with an *Investigation completed* message.

For example, if the user selects range A2:A40000 in Sheet 1 as containing the data to look for, and then selects range C2:C2000 in Sheet 2 as the range to search, and then enters the word "Yes" as the comment followed by selecting D as the column, the expected result when complete is that the user will see that cells in Column D in Sheet 1 will contain the word "Yes" if the data was found.

Comment: research using variant arrays.  It is always quicker to loop variant arrays than either Match or Find when using large amounts of data: https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Comment: And when using a variant array make sure to use a for loop as it is much quicker: https://analystcave.com/vba-for-loop-vs-for-each-loop/

Comment: For data sets this large I would stop using Excel. Put all the data in to a database. Force the field that holds emails to be unique. Now duplicates can never exist. Wash your hands.

Comment: @HackSlash Agreed. :) Unfortunately, I'm using this macro on workbooks provided to me from other areas of a very large organisation and these workbooks aren't related in any way (i.e. one day I could be comparing email addresses from various newsletter subscriptions, another day I could be comparing staff user IDs against training records, and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the article you linked and I did in the comments says, loop arrays they are quicker than either Find or Match and use a for loop:

```
Sub FindMatchingData()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim MySearchRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim findC As Variant
    
    Set myrange = Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:="Select the range of cells containing the data you are looking for:", Type:=8)
    
    Dim myRangeArray As Variant
    myRangeArray = myrange.Value
    
    Set MySearchRange = Application.InputBox( _
        Prompt:="Select the range you wish to investigate:", Type:=8)
    
    Dim MSRArray As Variant
    MSRArray = MySearchRange.Value
    
    Dim Response As String
    Response = InputBox(Prompt:="Specify the comment you wish to appear to indicate the data was found:")
    
    myoutputcolumn = Application.InputBox( _
    Prompt:="Enter the alphabetical column letter(s) to specify the column you want the message to appear in.")
        
    Dim outArray As Variant
    ReDim outArray(1 To UBound(myRangeArray, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    
    
        
    Set sht = myrange.Parent
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(myRangeArray, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To UBound(MSRArray, 1)
            If myRangeArray(i, 1) = MSRArray(j, 1) Then
                outArray(i, 1) = Response
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    
    sht.Cells(myrange.Row, myoutputcolumn).Resize(UBound(outArray, 1), 1).Value = outArray
            
    sht.Activate
    sht.Range("A1").Select
    
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Investigation completed."

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, that works really well. :) I thought about trying to use an array, but didn't think I could in this case. (I read somewhere it couldn't be used when you wanted the macro to write data, or something like that, but obviously I misunderstood what I was reading!)  In any case, I've tested your macro and it works very well. In fact, it works so well that I can leave Screen Updating enabled (which provides a much better user experience when selecting ranges from different worksheets). Thank you so much. Now all I have to do is try to get my head around your code to actually understand it! LOL